After some requests it losts the cookies and gives GraphQL Error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id'). "
I am using Query and resolver for fetching the articles data. In one request it fetches the 15 records. Fetching data limit is 15. After some request it lost the user Info/cookies an gives error GrapgQL Error and again asks for login.
server.js



const JwtMiddleware = require('./middlewares/JwtMiddleware');
const PostMiddleware = require('./middlewares/PostMiddleware');
const ApolloServer = require('./middlewares/ApolloMiddleware');


Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'something here',
  environment: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV
});


let app = express();

const originWhitelist = config.get('cors:whitelist');
const mediaTempPath = config.get(`principals:${process.env.PRINCIPAL}:media:tempUploadPath`);

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, cb) => {
    if (originWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }

    return cb(new Error(`Domain is not enabled in CORS whitelist, ${origin} config ${originWhitelist}`));
  },
  credentials: true
};

app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(compression());

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());

// used by jwt
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(async (req, res, next) => JwtMiddleware(req, res, next));

app.use('/static', express.static(mediaTempPath));
app = PostMiddleware(app, corsOptions);

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

app.use(function onError (err, req, res, next) {
  // The error id is attached to `res.sentry` to be returned
  // and optionally displayed to the user for support.
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log('##############################################################################################################');
    console.log('############################################### Error: #######################################################');
    console.error(err);
    console.log('##############################################################################################################');
    console.log('##############################################################################################################');
  }
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.end(res.sentry + '\n');
  Sentry.captureException(err);
  next();
});
const apolloServer = ApolloServer();

async function startServer () {
  await apolloServer.start();
  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    cors(corsOptions),
    json(),
    expressMiddleware(apolloServer, {
      context: async (el) => (el),
    }),
  );
}
startServer();

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(` GraphQL server ready at ${process.env.HTTP_PROTOCOL}localhost:${process.env.PORT}${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`);
  process.send = process.send || function () {
  };
  process.send('ready'); // we need this for pm2 reload in clustermode
});

// we need this for pm2 reload in clustermode
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  apolloServer.stop(function (err) {
    process.exit(err ? 1 : 0);
  });
});


Here is my ApolloMiddleware:

const depthLimit = require('graphql-depth-limit');
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
const { ApolloServer } = require('@apollo/server');
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql';

import { ApolloComplexityPlugin } from './ApolloComplexityPlugin';
const { simpleEstimator, fieldExtensionsEstimator } = require('graphql-query-complexity');

const schema = require('../schema');
const typeDefs = require('../schemas/schema');
const resolvers = require('../resolvers/resolvers');
const config = require('../config');
const PeaceError = require('../lib/PeaceError');
const ACLHelper = require('../lib/helpers/ACLHelper');

// security constants
const complexityMaxValue = 210;
const queryLengthMaxValue = 5500;
const querydepthMaxValue = 9;

const ApolloMiddleware = () => {
  return new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    validationRules: [
      depthLimit(querydepthMaxValue),
    ],
    playground: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV !== 'production',
    debug: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV !== 'production',
    inspect: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV !== 'production',
    connectToDevTools: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV !== 'production',
    introspection: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV !== 'production',
    context: async (args) => {
      const query = args.req.query.query || args.req.body.query || '';
      console.log('ApolloMiddleware: ', query);
      if (query) {
        // 1. check query length
        if (query.length > queryLengthMaxValue) {
          console.error('############################ QUERY_TOO_LARGE - Max ' + queryLengthMaxValue + '; - Query-Length: ' + query.length + ' ##################################################');
          console.error(query.slice(0, 50).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ') + '...');
          const queryToLarge = new PeaceError(new Error('Querie was too large. (Max: ' + queryLengthMaxValue + ' - Query-Length: ' + query.length + ')'), 'QUERY_TOO_LARGE', null, {
            origin: args.res
          });
          throw queryToLarge;
        }

        // 2. query allowed without userId
        const regexFromArray = new RegExp(config.get('queries:allowedWithoutUserId').join('|'), 'im');
        if (regexFromArray.test(query)) {
          return args;
        }

        const { user } = args.req;
        const slicedQuery = query.slice(0, 50).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ') + '...';
        console.log(`######################################## Query need valid userId: ${user ? user._id : 'no userId given'} #############################################`);
        console.log(slicedQuery);

        const isAllowed = ACLHelper.validateQueryACL(query, user);

        if (isAllowed) return args;

        console.error('##################################### Query has not required role ##############################################');
        console.error(slicedQuery);
        console.error('--------------------- user: ----------------------------');
        console.error(user);
        console.error('--------------------- isAllowed: ----------------------------');
        console.error(isAllowed);
        console.error('--------------------- args: ----------------------------');
        console.error(args);

        throw new GraphQLError(`Request not permitted ${slicedQuery}`, 'UNAUTHENTICATED');
      }
      return args;
    },
    formatError: (err) => {
      console.error('################################################# ApolloError #################################################');
      console.error('errObject:');
      console.error(err);
      console.error('stackTrace:');
      console.error(err.extensions.stacktrace);
      console.error('locations:');
      console.error(err.extensions.locations);
      console.error('################################################## /ApolloError ##############################################');
      Sentry.captureException(err);
      return err;
    },
    plugins: [
      ApolloComplexityPlugin({
        schema,
        estimators: [
          fieldExtensionsEstimator(),
          simpleEstimator({ defaultComplexity: 1 }),
        ],
        maximumComplexity: complexityMaxValue,
      }),
    ]
  });
};

module.exports = ApolloMiddleware;


Here is JWTMiddleware

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { pick } = require('lodash');

const  AuthenticationHelper = require('./../lib/helpers/AuthenticationHelper');
const PeaceUser = require('./../models/mongo/PeaceUser');
const PeaceError = require('../lib/PeaceError');
const config = require('../config');

const jwtPassword = config.get('jwt:password');
const originWhitelist = config.get('cors:whitelist');


const JwtMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const APPLICATION_NAME = process.env.APPLICATION_NAME;

  const accessToken = req.cookies['access-token'];
  const refreshToken = req.cookies['refresh-token'];

  if (!accessToken && !refreshToken) {
    return next();
  }

  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(accessToken, jwtPassword);
    // check if token got stolen from other application
    if (user.application !== APPLICATION_NAME) {
      console.error('JWT got stolen from different application', {
        username: user.username,
        application_name: user.application
      });
      const error = new PeaceError(
        new Error('PEACE JWT got stolen from different application'),
        'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR',
        null,
        {
          username: user.username,
          application_name: user.application
        }
      );
      return res.status(401).send({ error: error.message });
    }

    req.user = pick(user, '_id', 'username', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'roles');
    console.log('JWT: ', req.user);
    return next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error.. in JWT', e);
  }

  if (!refreshToken) {
    return next();
  }

  let data;

  try {
    data = jwt.verify(refreshToken, jwtPassword);

    // check if token got stolen from other application
    if (data.application !== APPLICATION_NAME) {
      const error = new PeaceError(
        new Error('PEACE JWT got stolen from other application'),
        'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR',
        null,
        {
          userId: data._id,
          username: data.username
        }
      );
      return res.status(401).send({ error: error.message });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error verifying refreshToken:', e);
  }

  const user = await PeaceUser.findOneByApplication({ _id: data._id });

  // token has been invalidated
  if (!user || user.count !== data.count) {
    if (originWhitelist.indexOf(req.headers.origin) >= 0) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-Type,x-requested-with');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    }

    res.clearCookie('access-token');
    res.clearCookie('refresh-token');
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Refresh token has been invalidated' });
  }

  const tokens = await AuthenticationHelper.createJWTsByUser(user);

  if ('accessToken' in tokens && 'refreshToken' in tokens) {
    AuthenticationHelper.createCookiesByJWT(tokens, res);

    req.user = {
      ...pick(user, 'username', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'roles'),
      _id: user._id.toString()
    };
  }
  return next();
};


module.exports = JwtMiddleware;


Here is my Resolver:


const _ = require('lodash');

import Article from '../../models/mysql/Article';
import ArticleElement from '../../models/mysql/ArticleElement';
import AssetList from '../../refactored/classes/AssetList';
const ArticleWorkflow = require('../../models/mongo/ArticleWorkflow');
const Media = require('../../models/mysql/Media');
const Navigation = require('../../models/mysql/Navigation');
const Palette = require('../../models/mongo/Palette');
const AnalyticsCache = require('../../models/mongo/AnalyticsCache');
const AuthorArticle = require('../../models/mysql/AuthorArticle');
const WorMedic = require('../../lib/helpers/WorMedicHelper');
const FilterHelper = require('../../lib/filters/FilterHelper');
const ArticleHelper = require('../../lib/helpers/ArticleHelper');
const ArticleValidator = require('../../lib/validators/ArticleValidator');
const { amazon: AmazonApiHelper } = require('../../lib/helpers/ApiHelper');
const TagHelper = require('../../lib/helpers/TagHelper');

const getObjectFilters = async (filters) => {
  const filtersObject = filters ? JSON.parse(filters) : {};
  if (filtersObject.tags && filtersObject.tags.length > 0) {
    const tags = await TagHelper.groupTagIdsByTagNames(filtersObject.tags);
    return { articleIds: await TagHelper.getArticleIdsWithTags(tags), ...filtersObject };
  }
  return filtersObject;
};
const getLimit = (requestedLimit, numberOfItems = 0) => {
  const limitLeftFromWorkflows = requestedLimit - numberOfItems;
  return limitLeftFromWorkflows > 0 ? limitLeftFromWorkflows : 0;
};


module.exports = {
  Query: {
    articles: async (obj, { limit = 15, offset = 0, order = 'DESC', orderField = 'start_date', filters = null, newArticles = false, elementType = null }, { req: { user } }) => {
      console.log('37: req.user: ', user._id);
      if (newArticles) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const articles = await ArticleWorkflow.find({ 'user._id': user._id, new: true, principal: PRINCIPAL });
        return articles.map(article => article.toObject().articleData);
      }

      const filtersObject = filters ? JSON.parse(filters) : {};
      if (filtersObject.tags && filtersObject.tags.length > 0) {
        const tags = await TagHelper.groupTagIdsByTagNames(filtersObject.tags);
        filtersObject.articleIds = await TagHelper.getArticleIdsWithTags(tags);
      }

      return await new Article().query(qb =>  {
        FilterHelper.filterArticles(qb, {
          limit,
          offset,
          order,
          orderField,
          filtersObject,
          elementType
        });
      }).fetchAll().then(async models => {
        // Merge articles from MySQL with current working copies to display YOUR current data
        const ids = models.map(model => model.get('id').toString());
        if (user) {
          const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.find({
            articleId: { $in: ids },
            'user._id': user._id,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            principal: PRINCIPAL
          });
          if (workflows) {
            const workflowsArticleIds = workflows.map(workflow => workflow.articleId);
            return models.map(model => {
              if (workflowsArticleIds.includes(model.get('id').toString())) {
                return workflows.find(w => w.articleId === model.get('id').toString()).toArticle();
              }

              return model.toJSON();
            });
          }
        }

        return models.toJSON();
      });
    },
    articlePaginator: async (_, {
      filters,
      limit: requestedlimit = 15,
      order = 'DESC',
      orderField  = 'start_date',
      page
    }, { req: { user } }) => {
      console.log('91: req.user: ', user._id);
      const setName = (obj) => {
        class WorArticle {}
        return Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, WorArticle.prototype);
      };
      const articleWorkflows = await ArticleWorkflow.find({ 'user._id': user._id, new: true, principal: PRINCIPAL });
      const limit = getLimit(requestedlimit, articleWorkflows?.length);
      const filtersObject = await getObjectFilters(filters);
      const elementType = null;
      const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
      // console.log('filtersObject: ' + filtersObject);
      try {
        const articleQuery = new Article().query(qb => {
          FilterHelper.filterArticles(qb, {
            limit,
            offset,
            order,
            orderField,
            filtersObject,
            elementType
          });
        });
        const articles = (await articleQuery.fetchAll()).toJSON();
        const counterQuery = new Article().query(qb => {
          FilterHelper.filterArticles(qb, {
            filtersObject
          });
        });
        const counter = (await counterQuery.count());
        return new AssetList(
          [...articleWorkflows.map(el => setName(el?.articleData)),
            ...articles.map(el => setName(el))],
          requestedlimit, counter);
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${e}`);
      }
    },
    article: async (obj, { id }, { req: { user } }) => {
      console.log('129: req.user: ', user._id);
      if(!user) {
        throw new Error('128: article.js: Unauthorised');
      }
      return ArticleHelper.fetchArticle(id, user ? user._id : null);
    }
  },
  Article: {
    elements: async ({ id }, args, { req: { user } }) => {
      console.log('138: req.user: ', user._id);
      if(!user) {
        throw new Error('136: article.js: Unauthorised');
      }
      return ArticleHelper.fetchArticleElements(id, user ? user._id : null);
    },
    teaserImage: async ({ teaserpic_id: teaserpicId, teaserImage }) => {
      if (teaserImage) {
        return teaserImage;
      }

      if (!teaserpicId) {
        return null;
      }

      return await new Media().where({ id: teaserpicId }).fetch().then(model => model ? model.toJSON() : null).catch(() => null);
    },
    articleStatus: ({ articleStatus }) => {
      switch (articleStatus) {
        case 'LOCKED':
          return 'LOCKED';
        case 'PUBLISHED':
          return 'PUBLISHED';
        case 'DEPUBLISHED':
          return 'DEPUBLISHED';
        case 'DELETED':
          return 'DELETED';
        default:
          return null;
      }
    },
    galleryImages: async ({ content_type: contentType, id }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      if(!userId) { console.log('170: req.user: ', userId); }
      if (contentType === 'ARTICLE') return null;
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.findOne({ articleId: id, principal: PRINCIPAL, 'user._id': userId });
      if (workflows) {
        return workflows.toObject().images;
      }

      try {
        const gallery = await new ArticleElement().where({ article_id: id, element_type: 'GALLERY' }).fetch({
          withRelated: [{ 'imageGallery.galleryMedia': query => query.orderBy('sorting', 'ASC') }]
        });
        return gallery.toJSON().imageGallery.galleryMedia;
      } catch (error) {
        return [];
      }
    },
    workflowId: async ({ id: articleId }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      if(!userId) { console.log('188: req.user: ', userId); }
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.findOne({ articleId, principal: PRINCIPAL, 'user._id': userId });
      if (workflows) {
        return workflows.toObject()._id;
      }
      return null;
    },
    workflowTimestamp: async ({ id: articleId }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      if(!userId) { console.log('197: req.user: ', userId); }
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.findOne({ articleId, principal: PRINCIPAL, 'user._id': userId });
      if (workflows) {
        return workflows.toObject().timestamp;
      }

      return null;
    },
    workflows: async ({ id: articleId }) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.find({ articleId, principal: PRINCIPAL });
      return workflows.map(workflow => workflow.toObject());
    },
    workflowGravity: async ({ id: articleId }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      if(!userId) { console.log('212: req.user: ', userId); }
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflowModels = await ArticleWorkflow.find({ articleId, principal: PRINCIPAL });
      const workflows = workflowModels.map(workflow => workflow.toObject());

      if (workflows.length === 0) return null;

      if (workflows.length === 1 && _.find(workflows, o => o.user._id === userId)) {
        return 'SAFE';
      } else if (workflows.length === 1 && !_.find(workflows, o => o.user._id === userId)) {
        return 'DANGEROUS';
      } else if (workflows.length > 1) {
        return 'CONFLICT';
      }
      return null;
    },
    tags: async ({ id }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      if(!userId) { console.log('229: req.user: ', userId); }

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.findOne({ articleId: id, principal: PRINCIPAL, 'user._id': userId });
      if (workflows) {
        if (workflows.articleData.tags) {
          return workflows.toObject().articleData.tags;
        }

        return null;
      }

      const article = await new Article().where({ id }).fetch();
      const tags = await article.getTags();
      return tags;
    },
    navigationNode: ({ navigation_id: id }) => {
      if (!id) return null;
      return new Navigation().where({ id }).fetch().then(node => node.toJSON());
    },
    pages: async ({ id: articleId }) => {
      const pageCount = await new ArticleElement().where({ article_id: articleId, element_type: 'PAGEBREAK' }).count();
      return pageCount + 1;
    },
    bookmarked: async ({ id }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      if(!userId) { console.log('253: req.user: ', userId); }

      const bookmarks = await Palette.countDocuments({
        userId: userId,
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        principal: PRINCIPAL,
        assets: { $elemMatch: { type: 'ARTICLE', assetId: id.toString() } }
      });
      return !!bookmarks;
    },
    seoData: async ({ id }) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      return AnalyticsCache.findOne({ identifier: id, principal: PRINCIPAL });
    },
    authors: async ({ id: articleId }, args, { req: { user } }) => {
      console.log('267: req.user: ', user._id);
      if (user) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const workflows = await ArticleWorkflow.findOne({ articleId, principal: PRINCIPAL, 'user._id': user._id });
        if (workflows && workflows.articleData.authors) {
          return workflows.toObject().articleData.authors.map(author => ({
            user_id: author,
            article_id: articleId,
            id: Math.round(Math.random() * (1000000 - 900000) + 900000)
          }));
        }
      }

      return new AuthorArticle().where({ article_id: articleId }).fetchAll().then(models => models.toJSON()).catch(() => null);
    },
    start_date: ({ start_date }) => {
      if (!start_date) return null;
      return WorMedic.toHumanReadableTimeFormat(start_date);
    },
    amazonData: ({ asin }) => {
      if (!asin) {
        return null;
      }

      return AmazonApiHelper.lookup(asin);
    },
    isValid: async ({ id: articleId }, args, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const workflow = await ArticleWorkflow.findOne({ articleId, principal: PRINCIPAL, 'user._id': userId });
      if (workflow) {
        if (workflow.isGallery) return ArticleValidator.isGalleryValid(workflow);
        return  ArticleValidator.isArticleValid(workflow);
      }

      // if there is no workflow, we assume that a article which is checkedIn should be valid
      return true;
    },
    pageUrl: async (params) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      return { id, navigation_id, content_type, speaking_url } = params;
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    autosaveArticleData: async (parent, { workflowId, articleData }, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      return ArticleHelper.saveArticleData({ workflowId, articleData, userId });
    },
    saveArticle: async (parent, { workflowId }, { req: { user: { _id: userId } } }) => {
      return ArticleHelper.saveArticle({ workflowId, userId });
    },
    setArticleStatus: async (parent, args) => {
      return ArticleHelper.setArticleStatus(args);
    }
  }
};





query GetArticlePaginator ($limit: Int, $page: Int, $order: SortOptions, $orderField: String, $filters: String) {
    articlePaginator(limit: $limit, page: $page, order: $order, orderField: $orderField, filters: $filters) {
        assets {
            ... on Article {
                id
                isValid
                articleStatus
                lock_reason
                workflowId
                workflows {
                    timestamp
                    user {
                        username
                        email
                    }
                }
                workflowGravity
                content_type
                caption
                title
                lead
                content_type
                teasertext
                start_date
                workflowTimestamp
                speaking_url
                meta_title
                meta_description
                meta_keywords
                promo
                pages
                bookmarked
                galleryImages {
                    id
                    image {
                        id
                        filename
                        mediatype
                    }
                }
                tags {
                    id
                    name
                }
                navigationNode {
                    id
                    breadcrumb
                    path
                }
                image: teaserImage {
                    id
                    filename
                    reference
                    legend
                    mediatype
                    bookmarked
                }
            }
        }
        cacheCreationTime
        hasMore
        filterCount
    }
}

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import possibleTypes from '../../webpack/possibleTypes.json';

import PeaceErrorModal from '../fragments/modals/PeaceErrorModal';

import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const GQL_URI = `//${process.env.GQL_ADDR}/graphql`;

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: GQL_URI,
  credentials: 'include',
  withCredentials: true
});

// Add the cookie value to headers for every request
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = Cookies.get('access-token'); // Read the cookie
  console.log(token);
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const errorLink = onError(({ networkError, graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
  // if json token expired, redirect to login page

  if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
    console.log('Error..Apolloclient.js 36');
    window.location.replace('/login');
  }

  const propsToPass = {
    graphQLErrors: graphQLErrors ? graphQLErrors[0] : {},
    networkError,
    operation
  };

  console.log(graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  console.log('graphQLErrors: ', graphQLErrors ? graphQLErrors : ''); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  console.log('network Error: ', networkError ? networkError : ''); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  ReactDOM.render(
    <PeaceErrorModal {...propsToPass} />,
    document.getElementById('peace_error_modal')
  );
});

console.log('authLink: ', authLink);
// use with apollo-client
// const link = errorLink.concat(authLink).concat(httpLink);
const link = authLink.concat(errorLink).concat(httpLink);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  credentials: 'include',
  connectToDevTools: process.env.SYSTEM_ENV !== 'production',
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    possibleTypes,
  })
});


export { client as ApolloClient };

After some requests it lost the cookies and again asks for login. Sometimes after 2nd page, sometimes after 45 pages and sometimes after 80 pages and so on gives the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')". Is there any problem in InMemoryCache? Here is my possibleTypes: 

{"WorkflowUnion":["Media","TeaserGroup","TeaserStatic","TeaserDynamic","Page","Navigation"],"WorkflowTypeUnion":["Article","Media","Author","TeaserGroup","TeaserStatic","TeaserDynamic","Page","Navigation"],"AssetUnion":["Article","Media","TeaserGroup","TeaserGroupWorkflow","TeaserStatic","TeaserStaticWorkflow","TeaserDynamic","TeaserDynamicWorkflow"],"TeaserUnion":["Article","TeaserStatic"],"AssignedUnion":["Article","Page"],"TagAssignmentUnion":["Article","Media","TeaserDynamic","Page"],"AssetListUnion":["Article","Media","Author","Tag","TeaserGroup","TeaserGroupWorkflow","TeaserStatic","TeaserStaticWorkflow","TeaserDynamic","TeaserDynamicWorkflow","Page","Navigation","UserManagement"]}
My application has different pages and for every pages different Query and resolvers are called. Lost of cookies happens with only one Resolver not in others. Somewhere user is missing and this resolver did not find user._id.
This error also used to flash(Query: articles) when I scroll the page 5-6 times before implementing the paginator(Query: mediaPaginator).
In other pages it is not giving this error but only in Article page. It lost somewhere user and cookies.  May be problem in resolver of Article, but unable to find.
It is very surprising that in other pages it is not loosing user or cookies. For all the pages same serverside code is written.
This problem never occurred on localhost always occurs on stage server.
If you need some more info for giving answer then let me know please.



Please fix up the formatting of the question. Also, please include the full stack trace of the error message as that might help diagnose the issue.

This is an error in your server-side code, not in your client code. You probably need to ask this question again with different tags and sharing server code & stack traces. The client code is irrelevant here.

Please let me know if possible where is the problem? I am struggling since long time for finding this error.

Your server replies to the request with INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. That's all we know. This is not a problem with your frontend, but with the server, so all I can say is that asking a question and providing all details on your frontend while omitting all details on your backend will not resolve this question. You have to ask a different question with a different angle.
